# Printing from a callback disrupts data printed by model,fit and data values are different

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a model using tensorflow. I have a custom callback which on epoch_end prints
out some data. specifically training accuracy or validation loss. With verbose=1
in model,fit tensorflow prints out the training loss, training accuracy, val_loss and val_accuracy as
shown below. Apparently is is also using tqdm to print the progress bar as well. Problem is if I printout the train accuracy captured from acc=logs.get('accuracy') in the callback at the end of the
epoch it is different from the value model.fit prints out. It is like the model.fit
accuracy value is not from the last batch of the epoch but from the next to last batch. Also you can see that my print out from the callback interrupts the model.fit printout. Note for epoch 1 I have accuracy as 0.9172 while the model.fit value is either 0.8805 or 0.8808.
Anyone know why this is or how to fix it ? Data is shown below;

```
Epoch 1/30
129/129 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.1791 - accuracy: 0.8805
training accuracy improved from   0.0000 to  0.9172 learning rate held at  0.002000 # callback printed data

129/129 [==============================] - 50s 389ms/step - loss: 3.1723 - accuracy: 0.8808 - val_loss: 3.1509 - val_accuracy: 0.5783
Epoch 2/30
129/129 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9478 - accuracy: 0.9671
training accuracy improved from   0.9172 to  0.9661 learning rate held at  0.002000 # calback printed data

129/129 [==============================] - 43s 333ms/step - loss: 0.9466 - accuracy: 0.9671 - val_loss: 0.9385 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 3/30
129/129 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4501 - accuracy: 0.9787
```

Comment: Instead of  downgrading the question please provide a comment that would enable me to improve it, I think for those experienced the question is clear with ample information. If not please clarify what is inadequate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK its a long  story but I am using tensorflow 2.1. I had supresed the annoying tensorflow warnings so I did not see any warnings. Out of suspicion I enabled warning and got the warning below.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch
 time (batch time: 0.0350s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0910s). Check your callbacks.
```

After much searching I found warning shows up if you run model.fit with verbose=1. Apparently this was a bug in the tensorflow release that causes accuracy data printed out by model.fit to be incorrect. If you run  model.fit with verbose=2 you do not get the warning and the accuracy data printed is correct. Problem solved